# Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.KotlinGradleModel'

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated Android Studio. And getting error like below :

[image]

Here is build.gradle file

[image]

Comment: Add build.gradle file with question also specify AS version

Comment: do this `re-download ....`

Comment: Several times I clicked on "Re-download dependencies and sync project(requires network)". But it's not working and I still have the same issue. Even I saw that my network connection is okay.

Comment: check your project offline mode or not